# Adding custom buttons to Kendo grid toolbar in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, telerik-grid

I am using Kendo tools for my ASP.NET Core application. I have a grid and I want to add custom buttons to the grid tool bar. I can easily add the export to excel button but I'm having a really hard time adding my custom buttons.

Currently I just have my buttons displayed above the grid, here are those buttons:

```
<a href='#' class='k-button' id='saveState'>Save Grid Settings</a>
<a href='#' class='k-button' id='clearState'>Clear Grid Settings</a>
```

Here is my grid:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<SylectusTL.ViewModels.Account.UserList>()
.Name("UserList")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(c => c.user_name).ClientTemplate(@"<a href=" + @Url.Content("/Account/UserProfile?caller='UserList'&user_id=#:data.user_id#") + ">#: user_name #</a>").Title("User Name");
    columns.Bound(c => c.full_name).Title("Name");
    columns.Bound(c => c.main_phone).Title("Phone").Width(150);
    columns.Bound(c => c.main_phone_ext).Title("Ext").Width(100);
    columns.Bound(c => c.email).Title("E-Mail");
    columns.Bound(c => c.admin).ClientTemplate("#= admin ? 'Y' : 'N' #").Title("Admin").Width(100).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center;" }).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center;" });
    columns.Bound(c => c.active).ClientTemplate("#= active ? 'Y' : 'N' #").Title("Active").Width(100).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center;" }).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center;" });
    columns.Bound(c => c.last_login).Title("Last Login").Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
})
.ToolBar(tools =>
{
    tools.Excel();
})
.Pageable(pageable => pageable
    .Refresh(true)
    .PageSizes(new int[] { 10, 20, 50 })
    .ButtonCount(5))
.Sortable(sortable => sortable
.AllowUnsort(true)
.SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn)
.ShowIndexes(true))
.Scrollable()
.Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
.Filterable()
.ColumnMenu()
.Excel(excel => excel
    .FileName("User List.xlsx")
    .Filterable(true)
    .ProxyURL(Url.Action("Excel_Export_Save", "Account"))
)
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .PageSize(20)
    .Read(read => read.Action("Users_Read", "Account").Data("additionalData"))
)
)
```

Is there a way to add a template of soemthing to the toolbar property, I want the buttons to display next to the export to excel button. I've looked up some tutorials and everything is showing using tools.template in my toolbar property but when I try that it says Template does not exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a `tools.Custom()` statement after the `tools.Excel()`.  This example creates a toolbar with the standard create button and a custom button for duplicating a row.

```
...
.ToolBar(toolbar =>
{
    toolbar.Create();
    toolbar.Custom()
        .HtmlAttributes ( new { onclick="master_duplicate(); return false;" } )
        .Name("duplicate")@* creates a button with class k-grid-duplicate *@
        .Text("Duplicate")
        .IconClass("k-icon k-i-copy")
        .Url("#")
        ;
})
...
```

and javascript

```
var dup_select_id; * used later in databound handler to automatically select the new duplicate;
function master_duplicate() {
    var grid = $('#master').data('kendoGrid');
    var data = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("Duplicate")",
        type: "POST",
        data: { masterID: data.id }
        })
        .done(function (data, status, jqXHR) {
            if (data.Data && data.Data.id) {
                dup_select_id = data.Data.id;
                grid.dataSource.read();
            }
        })
    ;
}
```

and there is other logic to hide the button when there is no selected row.

Comment: Did not work for me.  Only get one button, and don't get the excel button.

Comment: it should be mentioned that, apparently, in later kendo versions, .Url no longer exists on custom buttons.

Answer (score 0):

We can use **ClientTemplate** to add more than one column menu in existing. Below line of code we can refer for the same

```
.ToolBar(tools => {
             tools.ClientTemplate("<a class='column_Menu' style='float:right' id='columnMenuButton' href='\\#' />"+"<label for='HideEmptyIndicatores' style='float:right;padding-right: 20px;padding-left: 3px;'> Hide Empty Indicators</label> <input type='checkbox' style='height:15px;min-width:15px; float:right'; id = 'HideEmptyIndicatores' onchange='hideEmptyRateIndicators(this)'/> "); })
```

this line of code result in the below SS

[image]

Comment: This is useful but you will be required to build your entire button array if you use this as it will not allow you to use the other pre-made buttons at the same time as a client template.